# How to use Google Firebase admin in Play framework?

Tags: java, playframework, firebase-authentication, sbteclipse

I have added the dependency `"com.google.firebase" % "firebase-admin" % "6.10.0"`  in a Play project, but when I tried to import FirebaseOptions, it shows that no import available.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you've skipped step number two, but here are all steps what you need to do:

1. Add to build.sbt `libraryDependencies += "com.google.firebase" % "firebase-admin" % "6.10.0"`
2. Download dependencies to your local project: run `sbt update` in your project folder
3. Add import statement to your class `import com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions`